# How do I resolve this issue where my Meteor Android app doesn't connect?

Tags: android, meteor, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to run my Meteor Android app on my phone, the app installs on the phone as expected but it doesn't connect, it seems to be a problem creating a websocket based on the IP address of the phone.

Could this be an something relating to setting up a proxy service on Windows 11 to allow connections to the WSL virtual machine?

`Update`: I've installed a network analysis app on my phone and I can ping my Ubuntu IP address `192.168.115.214` but port 3000 is blocked.  If I open a browser on my win 11 laptop and go to `192.168.115.214:3000` my app appears.

in the dev tools I get this:

[image]

In my app:

`ROOT_URL=https://192.168.1.101:3000 meteor run --mobile-server 192.168.1.101:3000 android-device --port=3000`

Mobile Phone IP:

```
192.168.1.101
```

Windows (11):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : ::acdb:90ff:ec22:b5d
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : ::f1a3:d3f5:e2f1:8baa
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::acdb:90ff:ec22:b5d%8
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.105
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d510:778:9360:2b5c%25
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.112.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Ubuntu (WSL):

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.115.214  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.127.255
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe08:2510  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:15:5d:08:25:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 90695  bytes 28825428 (28.8 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 19863  bytes 3402580 (3.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: You should not connect to the ip of your phone but to the ip of your windows pc. The ip of your phone is completely irrelevant and you should use it nowhere.

Comment: I tried using the win IP too, still no success.  Think there's something else I need to do, not sure what though.

Comment: `ROOT_URL=https://192.168.1.101:3000` is pointing to the phone's local ip. Shouldn't it point to `192.168.115.214`? I think thats what @blackapps tried to say.

Comment: Wouldn't it need to connect to my Windows IP though?  I currently have it set on windows via powershell so that all IPs are forwarded to `192.168.115.214` and I've also got the port 3000 open.  So I can access via the browser on mobile using the windows IP (192.168.1.105) at port 3000 so I'm expecting the app to use the same.  In all honesty I think this could be a Meteor bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone should be connected to the same Wifi network and you need to enter your network ip address

and you can run

```
meteor run --settings settings.json android-device --port http://<IP-ADDR>:3000 --mobile-server=http://<IP-ADDR>:3000
```